# Работа с аргументами функции в с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

функция write_stats, которая принимает два аргумента - набор данных и выводной поток, и до выводного потока записывает 3 статические данные о данных: минимум макс и ср.ариф(всех данных). Например, у нас есть 1.23, 5.44, -23, а он выдаст потом

min: -23.00 
max: 5.44 
mean: 9.89

числа должны быть с двумя цифрами после запятой

Comment: Решать кому? Кто выиграет тендер?...

Answer (score 3):

Не думаю, что вы это проходили, и вам такой код понадобится. Просто тут не делают за вас задание, а помогают понять или исправлять. Если вы что то тут поймете, это уже плюс для вас:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <iomanip>
using std::valarray;

void
write_stats(std::initializer_list<double> list, std::ostream& os) {
    valarray<double> v = list;
    os << std::setprecision(2)
       << std::setiosflags(std::ios_base::showpoint | std::ios_base::fixed)
       <<"min: " << v.min() << '\n'
       <<"max: " << v.max() << '\n'
       << "mean: " << v.sum() / v.size();
}

int main()
{   
    write_stats({1.23, 5.446, 6.5467, 2.875 -23}, std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ахаха, вангую что объяснить как это работает ТС не осилит.